# How to deploy Oracle Forms applications to Oracle Web logic server

Tags: deployment, weblogic, middleware, oracleforms, fusion

I am new to weblogic. In older days I used to work with Oracle Developer suite forms and reports developer 9i and 10g. In those days Oracle Developer suite installation automatically installed not only the forms and reports developer tools, but also the Oracle Application server to which we used to deployed the applications. So, only one installation was necessary to get everything. But now after 10 years, when I want to use Oracle Forms 12c, I did install it but there was no app.server, so, upon some research, I also installed Weblogic server. But I simply have no idea how to connect Oracle Forms developer to the Weblogic server so that when I run a forms module in the forms developer, the web logic application server render that form module in the browser like Oracle 9i or 10g AS used to do. Can someone please guide me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "connect" WebLogic to Forms.  You install one into the other.  WLS is the "application server" and "Forms" is a technology WLS is hosting.

The install is a few steps but not very difficult.

1. Ensure you have a 64bit JDK (version 8) installed. Do not attempt to use newer or older versions.
2. Install Fusion Middleware Infrastructure 12.2.1.4 (this is WLS)
3. Install the "Forms and Reports 12.2.1.4" software into the same Home you created for step 2
4. Run the Repository Creation Utility (RCU). This will create database schemas needed to maintain the WebLogic Server environment.
5. Run the Configuration Wizard.  This will create a WebLogic Server Domain and the individual servers for Forms and any other components you choose to setup.
6. The servers must be started the first time in order to complete the configuration.  In this order, start Node Manager, Admin Server, and WLS_FORMS.

You now have a complete Forms setup (design time tools and runtime servers).  If you also want Reports, there are a few post configuration steps required to complete the setup.

This is mostly just an overview of the setup.  Referring to the documentation is a good idea.

Download links, documentation links, and many other useful information can be found on the Oracle Forms product page: https://www.oracle.com/application-development/technologies/forms/forms.html